# SCSS dinámico con variables ya definidas

Tags: css, scss

Estoy itentando ciclar algunos valores para concatenarlos con unas variables ya establecidas y solo darle una profundidad de color basado en una especie de arreglo.

Estas son mis variables con los colores ya definidos

```
$brand-primary-surface-0: #fafafaff;
$brand-primary-surface-25: #f5f5f5ff;
$brand-primary-surface-50: #ebebebff;
$brand-primary-surface-75: #d8d8d8ff;
$brand-primary-surface-100: #c0c0c0ff;
$brand-primary-surface-200: #a1a1a1ff;
$brand-primary-surface-300: #767676ff;
$brand-primary-surface-400: #5c5c5cff;
$brand-primary-surface-600: #2e2e2eff;
$brand-primary-surface-700: #242424ff;
$brand-primary-surface-800: #1c1c1cff;
$brand-primary-surface-900: #151515ff;
```

Este es el mapa que quiero ciclar para que tome un valor diferente en cada ciclo

```
$deeps: 0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900;
```

Por último estoy ciclando de esta forma para armar de forma dinámica las clases que inyectaré a unos componentes

```
@each $deep in $deeps {
    .brand-primary-surface-#{$deep} {
        background-color: $brand-primary-surface-#{$deep};
    }
}
```

El resultado que esperaba es como este

```
.brand-primary-surface-0 {
    background-color: #fafafaff;
}

.brand-primary-surface-25 {
    background-color: #f5f5f5ff;
}

.brand-primary-surface-50 {
    background-color: #ebebebff;
}
```

En cambio recibo este error

```
Button 
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/components/Button/Button.scss undefined
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
94 │         background-color: $brand-primary-surface-#{$deep};
   │                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src\colores.scss 94:27                 @import
  src\components\Button\Button.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
```

Parece que no le gustó como concatené las variables. Soy un poco nuevo en SCSS, que me recomiendan?

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un map utilizando las llaves con los valores que tienes en los `$deeps` y los valores serían los colores que ya tienes definidos y luego utilizar `@each $key, $value` sobre el map.

Ejemplo:

```
$brand-primary-surface: (
  0: #fafafaff,
  25: #f5f5f5ff,
  50: #ebebebff,
  75: #d8d8d8ff,
  100: #c0c0c0ff,
  200: #a1a1a1ff,
  300: #767676ff,
  400: #5c5c5cff,
  600: #2e2e2eff,
  700: #242424ff,
  800: #1c1c1cff,
  900: #151515ff
);

@each $key, $value in $brand-primary-surface {
  .brand-primary-surface-#{$key} {
    background-color: $value;
  }
}
```

Esto produce:

```
.brand-primary-surface-0 {
  background-color: #fafafaff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-25 {
  background-color: #f5f5f5ff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-50 {
  background-color: #ebebebff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-75 {
  background-color: #d8d8d8ff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-100 {
  background-color: #c0c0c0ff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-200 {
  background-color: #a1a1a1ff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-300 {
  background-color: #767676ff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-400 {
  background-color: #5c5c5cff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-600 {
  background-color: #2e2e2eff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-700 {
  background-color: #242424ff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-800 {
  background-color: #1c1c1cff;
}
.brand-primary-surface-900 {
  background-color: #151515ff;
}
```

Pero si las variables que ya tienes no pueden cambiar por alguna razón, entonces podrías utilizar `map-get`:

```
$brand-primary-surface-0: #fafafaff;
$brand-primary-surface-25: #f5f5f5ff;
$brand-primary-surface-50: #ebebebff;
$brand-primary-surface-75: #d8d8d8ff;
$brand-primary-surface-100: #c0c0c0ff;
$brand-primary-surface-200: #a1a1a1ff;
$brand-primary-surface-300: #767676ff;
$brand-primary-surface-400: #5c5c5cff;
$brand-primary-surface-600: #2e2e2eff;
$brand-primary-surface-700: #242424ff;
$brand-primary-surface-800: #1c1c1cff;
$brand-primary-surface-900: #151515ff;

$deeps: 0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 600, 700, 800, 900;

@each $deep in $deeps {
  .brand-primary-surface-#{$deep} {
    background-color: map-get((
      0: $brand-primary-surface-0,
      25: $brand-primary-surface-25,
      50: $brand-primary-surface-50,
      75: $brand-primary-surface-75,
      100: $brand-primary-surface-100,
      200: $brand-primary-surface-200,
      300: $brand-primary-surface-300,
      400: $brand-primary-surface-400,
      600: $brand-primary-surface-600,
      700: $brand-primary-surface-700,
      800: $brand-primary-surface-800,
      900: $brand-primary-surface-900
    ), #{$deep});
  }
}
```